# Добавление navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, android-navigation-drawer

Как мне в проект добавить navigation drawer, если я создаю не общий toolbar, а добавляю его отдельно в каждый фрагмент.

```
    Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Что тогда писать в MainActivity? Попробовал использовать стандартный способ добавления navigation drawer, но он требует, чтобы toolbar был прописан в самом активити, а не в его фрагментах.

```
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
```

Comment: Добавить кастомный как основной а в фрагментах его перетпределять под свои нужды. Крутить вертеть как хотеть. @override

Answer (score 1):

Решал раньше эту проблему как-то так.

Во фрагменте:

```
    AppCompatActivity actionBar = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
    actionBar.setSupportActionBar(mToolbar); //собственный тулбар фрагмента
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = actionBar.findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), mDrawerLayout, mToolbar, R.string.app_name,
            R.string.app_name);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
```

В активити:

```
mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
final NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.main_item);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {...}
```

Источник на английском стаке [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39140911/6824996). Там же описаны и другие способы.

Comment: Почему раньше решал? Теперь как-то по другому делаешь, или есть более надежный способ реализации данного интерфейса

Comment: @3Jlou4uTep  Нет, я хотел сказать, что когда-то у меня была такая проблема и я её так решил) я на самом деле не знаю никакого другого решения кроме тех, что по ссылке на стаке.